# How to update JSON value in mysql database using X Dev API for relational table

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, mysql-json, mysql-x-devapi

I am trying to emulate `UPDATE user SET userDetails = JSON_SET(userDetails, '$.name', 'Alok') WHERE id = 1;` to update JSON value using X Dev API.

```js
var updateValue = `JSON_SET(userDetails, '$.name', 'Alok')`
var result = await db.getTable('user').update().set('userDetails', updateValue).where(`id = 1`).execute()
```

I am getting error

```
Error: Invalid JSON text: "Invalid value." at position 0 in value for column 'user.userDetails'.
```

Suppose I dont want to run raw SQL query. I want to do this using X Dev API. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try: `... .update().set('userDetails', mysqlx.expr(updateValue)).where(\`id = 1\`) ...`.